# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode()

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu

I've searched on the Internet about this error. Somebody told me that my computer is missing lib xml for php. But I don't know how to install it on Ubuntu 12.04 TLS.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function **uft8_decode()**

The function name is [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/utf8_decode), not `uFT8_decode()`.

`var_dump(function_exists('utf8_decode'));` should tell you if it's available. If this returns `bool(false)`, then `php-xml` package is probably missing in your PHP installation. Make sure it is installed. If it isn't, ask your hosting provider to update / install it.

Comment: Sorry, but I used utf8_decode()

Comment: @user2767553: Okay, what does the `var_dump(function_exists('utf8_decode'));` output?

Comment: @AmalMurali Where did you get `uFTdecode()` from?

Comment: @user555 The question title

Comment: @user555: Look at the [question title](http://i.imgur.com/cUf85FF.png).

Comment: @AmalMurali Well it says `uft8_decode()` and not `uFTdecode()`.

Comment: @user555: `FT` was capitalized to highlight the typo. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: @AmalMurali I get that, but you are still missing the `8` and the `_`. I think you meant to write `uFT8_decode()`.

Comment: @user555: OH. You're right. Thanks, I've now updated the answer to reflect this. :)

Comment: @user2767553 The PHP man page for `function_exists()` states: `A function name may exist even if the function itself is unusable due to configuration or compiling options.` What does `var_dump(is_callable('utf8_decode'));` return?