# Call to undefined function utf8_decode

Tags: php, php-7

I looked at other SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707870/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-utf8-decode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701730/utf8-endecode-removed-from-php7) about this error: **FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode**

Both answers say that installing php-xml will fix the error. But that didn't work. I ran `sudo apt install php-xml` which installed both php-xml and php7.0-xml and I restarted php-fpm and nginx. But I still get the same error.

Also checked `function_exists('utf8_decode')` and it returns false. So the error is obviously thrown when utf8_decode is called.

The server is Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 7.0. Here's the phpinfo output (PDF): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3GpdAvwm4fOaWMwb0JkTFQyb0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Remember to restart apache2 after the install. I would recommend to restart the server, because i had to do it for the same issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK so I figured it out. This was related to missing files in /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/

Normally there should be an xml.ini file there but that file was missing because of how I had installed, uninstalled and re-installed PHP. That operation was not done cleanly. After installing PHP from the PPA I had uninstalled it, deleted many files from /etc/php/ (which is not recommended. Use `apt-get purge` instead).

So long story short, this worked:

`sudo apt-get purge php-xml php7.0-xml`

`sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Answer (score 8):

Run `php -v` to check the version of **PHP**.

If you're running version is *5.6*, the solution is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
```

Otherwise, run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

Answer (score 0):

looking for the modules that I have installed in php

`php -m | grep -i xml`

after I run this command

```
yum --enablerepo remi install php-xml
```

and restart apache

```
sudo service httpd restart
```